# How to speed up a movie/gif reproduction on Android

Tags: android, gif

Having a `View` to reproduce the GIF and a `Seekbar` to let the user play the gif faster or slower, I am having the problem to successfully implement the speed.

The `GifView` to reproduce a gif to the useris working perectly:

```
public class GifView extends View {

    private int gifRawId;   
    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                         int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        if(gifRawId!=0) {
            setFocusable(true);
            gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(gifRawId);
            gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
            movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
            movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
            movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                             int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
    }

    public int getMovieWidth(){
        return movieWidth;
    }

    public int getMovieHeight(){
        return movieHeight;
    }

    public long getMovieDuration(){
        return movieDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);


            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

    public void setGifRawId(int gifDrawable, Context context) {
        this.gifRawId = gifDrawable;
        init(context);
    }
}
```

Then, I got a `SeekBar` to let the user increase or decrease the speed of the reproduction. But `relTime = (int)(((now - mMovieStart) % dur) / gifSpeed);` not work ok because it doesn't work correctly (where `gifSpeed` is the value gotten from the `Seekbar`).

How can I speed up the reproduction of the gif/video?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the order of terms in `relTime`. The correct answer was:

```
int relTime = (int)((((now - mMovieStart) * gifSpeed) % dur));
```

If anyone wants the complete code for GifView with speed control, next I post it:

```
public class GifView extends View {

    private int gifRawId;
    private double gifSpeed = 1;    
    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                         int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        if(gifRawId!=0) {
            setFocusable(true);
            gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(gifRawId);
            gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
            movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
            movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
            movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
        //setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public int getMovieWidth(){
        return movieWidth;
    }

    public int getMovieHeight(){
        return movieHeight;
    }

    public long getMovieDuration(){
        return movieDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int)((((now - mMovieStart) * gifSpeed) % dur));


            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

    public void setGifRawId(int gifDrawable, Context context) {
        this.gifRawId = gifDrawable;
        init(context);
    }

    public void setGifSpeed(double gifSpeed){
        this.gifSpeed = gifSpeed;
    }
}
```